# Arduino IDE not seeing Arduino library

Tags: ide, build

Working on my first real Arduino project.

I opened my code in the Arduino IDE and hit build and I get errors "not declared in the scope" on every single call to the Arduino library. For instance, digitalWrite, digitalRead, INPUT, OUTPUT, etc.

I open other projects with my Arduino IDE and they build fine, so it's clearly the code in this project. I've restarted. No change.

Ideas?

Comment: If it's "clearly" the code in the project them *maybe* it would be a good idea to *show* us that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the problem was, but I included `Arduino.h` and everything worked. This is a hack, but an effective one. If someone else knows what I did wrong, let me know.

Comment: It would have been better to develop the question into something where the answer followed from it.  Given your answer, it seems likely that you were not using an .ino (or .pde) extension.  Something that would have revealed itself if you'd put verbose output from the compilation stage.  You should do that in future questions, along with the code, etc.

Comment: No, was using an ino. The only posting of code would have been my entire project, which is not small. Since the code belongs to my client, I have concerns about doing that. I would love help, but the price is a bit high in this case and I'll have to settle for a hack workaround.

Comment: I'm not going to down-vote this, but for me, what you're describing as an answer would have to be demonstrated to be believed.  If you *have* an .ino file but the code you're actually talking about is *in a non-.ino file*, e.g. header, then the answer makes sense, but this fact should be mentioned somewhere.  The [Arduino build process](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/sketch-build-process/) does add this `#include` to your .ino files, originally called `WProgram.h` since **W**iring, before "Arduino" even existed.